# How to enable Amazon S3 Cross Account Bucket Policy with Block All Access on?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, axios, xmlhttprequest, http-headers

I am trying to enable Amazon S3 Cross Account bucket policy, the user is in the same root account we call `UserA`, this is the only account under the root account and I am trying to add it to a bucket so that users using my application can upload images and it is stored in the bucket, `UserA` needs read/write or GET/PUT permissions.

However, I need to disable the fourth option in order for it to work correctly as seen below.

After testing uploading on my application, with Block All Public access enabled, I get XMLHTTPRequest 405 Forbidden error.

The problem is that the bucket becomes public when I uncheck the fourth option, is there another way I can block all public access and still have the `UserA` be able to upload and fetch images on the bucket so it can be secure as possible?

[image]

This is my `bucket` policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1689384910025",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1689384810241",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789101:user/UserA"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::imagebucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my inline IAM Policy for `UserA`

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1689371326124",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::imagebucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The BPA settings don't make anything public. When enabled they prevent actions that would result in a public bucket or public objects. If something becomes public when you disable one of these options it's because it was already made public independently of the BPA setting.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your situation is:

- `Bucket-A` in AWS Account A
- `Bucket-B` in AWS Account B
- IAM Role `Role-A` in AWS Account A

You would need:

- A policy on `Role-A` that permits:

  - Read access (`GetObject` and presumably `ListBucket`) from `Bucket-A`
  - Write access (`PutObject`) to `Bucket-B`
- A **Bucket Policy** on `Bucket-B` that grants write access for `Role-A`

Based on the information you have provided, **`Role-A` does not have permission to access *both* buckets**. If the bucket policy you have shown is for `Bucket-B`, then it would be sufficient.

**Side-note:** When copying objects *TO* a bucket owned by a different account, use `ACL=public-read` otherwise the objects will not be 'owned' by the destination bucket. Alternatively, [Disable ACLs on `Bucket-B`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ensure-object-ownership.html) to avoid this problem.